# node REPL "on exit" event

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to trigger a function that's called when the user types `.exit` or [Ctrl][D]s the script?

Something like:

```
repl.start().on('exit', function() {
    console.log("Thanks for using customized Node REPL!");
});
```

(Except, of course, I'd actually put *useful* code instead of the `console.log`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
repl.start().rli.on('close', function() {
    console.log("Thanks for using customized Node REPL!");
});
```

REPL uses the [`Readline`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html) module, which emits a [`Close`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html#event_close_) event. From the docs:

> **Event: 'close'**
>
> `function () {}`
>
> Emitted whenever the in stream receives a `^C` or `^D`, respectively known
>   as SIGINT and EOT. This is a good way to know the user is finished
>   using your program.

Comment: Could you add the source back please?

Comment: Sorry, there is documentation. I've expanded the answer. The source is at https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master